# definition of (cartesian) product of sets

Tags: general-topology

In Ronald Brown's book "Topology and Groupoids" we have, in Appendix A3, the following definition of what a (cartesian) product is:

> Let $\{X_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in L}$ be a family of sets and let $X$ be the set of all families $x=(x_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}$ such that $x_{\lambda}\in X_{\lambda}$. Then $X$ is called a *product* of the family $(X_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}$ and is denoted by
> $$\prod_{\lambda\in L}X_{\lambda}.$$

Shouldn't the definition read instead:

> ... and let X be the set of all **tuples** x

I am referring to the 2006 version of his book, further corrected in 2020 which he makes available [here](https://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html). There is a list of errata further down on that same page but the above section does not appear there.

Comment: Sure, yes, tuples or sequences or functions or something.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. [Here is why.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)

Comment: A tuple vaguely implies ordered, whereas $L$ is not ordered. I agree, I wouldn't call it a family, either, but the correct terminology, all functions $L\to\bigcup_{l\in L} X_l,$ is a bit much to swallow. In set theory, tuples are defined inductively, and hence only on countable sets.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I try to abide by this rule but here I claim extenuating circumstances as I feared a typo, misspelling or even some semantically-loaded style change (e.g. bold or italics) and I wanted to reproduce from the book as faithfully as possible.

Comment: Nothing in that picture was such that it was difficult to reproduce with Mathjax and mark-up, as I easily demonstrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a typo.

What is a "tuple"? Normally we think of a "tuple" with index set $I$ as a function with domain $I$. So, viewed as a set of ordered pairs, a tuple $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ would be the set
$$\{ (i,x_i)\mid i\in I\}.$$
For index sets that are of the form $I=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$, we often denote this as $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$, with the understanding that this just means "$a_1$ is the image of $1$, $a_2$ is the image of $2$, etc."

What is a "family"? A family of sets is the result of applying the Axiom (Schema) of Replacement to a set $I$, together with the indexing set $I$. Recall that the Axiom (Schema) of Replacement says, roughly, that if you have a set $I$, and you have a way of associating a set $F(i)$ to each $i\in I$, then the collection $\{F(i)\mid i\in I\}$ is also a set. Roughly, that if you have a way of replacing each element of $I$ with a well-defined set, then the result will also be a set. So a family $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ means that you have an indexing $I$ which is a set, for each $i\in I$ you have a set $X_i$, and if you take the set $I$ and you replace each $i\in I$ with $X_i$, you get a set. (So that the "family" is indeed a set, and thus an object of study in set theory).

So what does the statement

> [a family] $x=(x_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}$ such that $x_{\lambda}\in X_{\lambda}$

yield? It would yield a set that is the result of applying a function $x\colon L\to \cup_{\lambda\in L}X_{\lambda}$ with the property that $x(\lambda)=x_{\lambda}$ lies in $X_{\lambda}$. So it is clearly equivalent to a "tuple". (Remember that in standard set theory, *everything* is a set; so there is no distinction between things that are sets and things that are elements, because there is nothing which is one but never the other; every set is an element of a set, every element of a set is itself a set.)

However, as has been noted, there is a vague implication of "order" in "tuple". So we *often* say "pair", "triple", "$n$-tuple", and "tuple" with an elided "ordered". Technically we would need to *say* "ordered pair", "ordered tuple", but we often do not, to the point that if you hear "pair", you will usually assume we mean "ordered pair", and if you hear "tuple", you will usually assume that it is an "ordered tuple", that is, that the indexing set $I$ has some inherent (total) order on it. So it is less prone to potentially being misleading to call these "families" rather than "tuples."

A more common way of defining the product is to define it as an explicit set of functions. That is,
$$\prod_{\lambda\in L} X_{\lambda}$$
is usually defined to be the set of all functions $x\colon L\to\bigcup\limits_{\lambda\in L} X_{\lambda}$ such that $x(\lambda)\in X_{\lambda}$. Then we denote the value $x(\lambda)$ by $x_{\lambda}$, and the function $x$ by $(x_{\lambda})$. They all amount to the same object.

---

To see this explicitly let's consider $L=\{1,2\}$, and sets $X_1=\{x,y\}$, $X_2=\{z,w\}$.

An $L$-tuple is a function with domain $L$. The product $\prod\limits_{\lambda\in L} X_\lambda$ would be the collection of all $L$-tuples $f\colon L\to X_1\cup X_2$ with the property that $f(1)\in X_1$ and $f(2)\in X_2$. We can represent $f$ as a set of ordered pairs, like any function, or by giving its values in specific order, $(f(1),f(2))$.

*Note:* We can do that because the set $L$ has an inherent order that we recognize. If it was simply $L=\{\star,\bullet\}$, we would need to agree that to represent a function $f\colon L\to X_1\cup X_2$ as an ordered pair, we would list one particular image first, and make that both explicit and clear.

So the elements would be the following four functions; I list them as explicit functions, and as $L$-tuples written as above, and as "families" as given by Brown. The latter I will use letters other than $x$ to avoid confusion.

$$\begin{array}{l|lc|lc|l}
&\text{function} & & L\text{-tuple} & & \text{family}\\
\hline
f_1 & 1\mapsto x &\quad & (x,z) & \quad &(a_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}\\
& 2\mapsto z & & &&a_1=x, a_2=z\\
\hline
f_2 & 1\mapsto x & \quad &(x,w) & \quad & (b_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}\\
&2\mapsto w & &&&b_1=x, b_2=w\\
\hline
f_3 & 1\mapsto y & \quad & (y,z) & \quad & (c_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}\\
& 2\mapsto z & && & c_1=y, c_2=z\\
\hline
f_4 & 1\mapsto y & \quad & (y,w) & \quad & (d_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}\\
& 2\mapsto w & & && d_1=y, d_2=z\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

The product $\prod\limits_{\lambda\in L}X_{\lambda}$ can be viewed either as:

1. The set of functions $\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\}$, described explicitly in the second column of the table above.
2. The set of $L$-tuples $\{(x,z), (x,w), (y,z), (y,w)\}$.
3. The set of $L$-families, $\{(a_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}, (b_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}, (c_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}, (d_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}\}$.

They all represent the same object. The main difficulty with "tuples" is that without having an inherent order in $L$, it becomes impossible to describe in the abstract a set of "$L$-tuples" as "lists".

Comment: I do see why the product can be viewed as a (singular _a_) family of sets wherein each set is actually the graph of a function. What I do not see is how it can be viewed as the set of ALL such families.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus That makes zero sense. Think about $\{x,y\}\times \{a,b\}$. It's elements are **all** functions with domain $\{1,2\}$, which have the property that the image of $1$ lies in $\{x,y\}$ and the image of $2$ lies in $\{a,b\}$. It is **all** such functions **by definition**. In the definition, the "family" is in fact the "graph", not a collection of graphs.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus (I say "zero sense" because, in the context of your original question, I do not see how changing "family" to "tuple" would change that. Tuples are just the graphs of a function. So you would also say: "I do see why the product can be viewed as a collection of tuples where each of them is the graph of a function. What I do not see is how it can be viewed as the set of *all* such tuples",

Comment: Thank you! "the set of all graphs" (instead of "the set of all families") does indeed make sense. However I've never seen a graph described as a "family (of sets)". A family of sets indexed by what? Your explanation on "zero sense" is also correct.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus As you accepted, I was adding an explicit example in which I give the three "standard" descriptions of the elements of the product: as a set of functions, as a set of $L$-tuples, as a set of $L$-families.

Comment: Yes, in retrospect I see that the root of my inability to parse the definition as given in Ronald Brown's text is that I thought a "family" as a mathematical object consists of sets, whereas I now see that a family's elements can be "primitive" things such as numbers, and not necessarily sets. Thank you again.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Are you aware that in standard set theory, **everything** is a set? Numbers are sets. Everything is a set. There are no objects that are not sets.